# Inline formatting LocalTime.now() in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to inline format my LocalTime variable if it's default. This is what I currently have:

```
...
var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1)
...
```

The result when I create the object could be for example 15:05:22.2463181 when I'm only looking for 15:05

When I try to do the following:

```
var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT))
```

It then complains with a Type Missmatch stating I should use a String? instead of LocalTime.

How do I go about inline formatting it to match, for example: 15:02?

Cheers

Comment: I feel like you may believe that `LocalTime` has a format. It does not. Though you can zero-out the seconds and nanoseconds by calling `truncateTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)`. But beyond that, you use a `DateTimeFormatter` when converting a temporal object to a string and vice versa.

Comment: @Slaw With an example or two, that would make a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse string to get LocalTime like this.

```
   var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)),DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT))
```

Also you can make it as reusable extension function like below:

```
   fun LocalTime.formatTime(formatStyle: FormatStyle= FormatStyle.SHORT): LocalTime = LocalTime.parse(this.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(formatStyle)),DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(formatStyle))
```

Usage:

```
var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).formatTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
```

(or)

```
 var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).formatTime()
```

As formatTime has default value as `FormatStyle.SHORT`

Answer (score 0):

A `LocalTime` does not have a format, "inline" or otherwise. It is simply data representing a time with no date nor timezone. It's when you convert a temporal object to a `String`, or vice versa, that you use a "format". That format is specified by the `DateTimeFormatter`, not by the temporal object.

That said, temporal classes such as `LocalTime` do implement `toString()`, and so they have to use a default format. Here is [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString()) of `LocalTime#toString()`:

> Outputs this time as a String, such as 10:15.
>
> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - HH:mm
> - HH:mm:ss
> - HH:mm:ss.SSS
> - HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
> - HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

<sup>- See [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to understand what those formats mean.</sup>

That means when the seconds and nanoseconds are zero then `LocalTime#toString()` will use the `HH:mm` pattern. You can zero-out those fields with the [`truncatedTo(ChronoUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) method. So, this approach seems closest to your desire to have some sort of "inline format", as it does not involve using a custom `DateTimeFormatter`.

Here's an example demonstrating the above information:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

fun main() {
    val time = LocalTime.of(12, 30, 45, 987_654_321);
    val truncatedTime = time.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    println("time.toString()          -> $time")
    println("time.format('HH:mm')     -> ${time.format(formatter)}")
    println("truncatedTime.toString() -> $truncatedTime")
}
```

Output:

```
time.toString()          -> 12:30:45.987654321
time.format('HH:mm')     -> 12:30
truncatedTime.toString() -> 12:30
```

---

Where you apply the solution depends on how exactly the code you've provided is used. For instance, maybe all you need to do is:

```kotlin
var timeOutgoing: LocalTime = LocalTime.now().plusHours(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
```

But since you've tagged this question with [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot), perhaps this code is part of e.g., an HTTP response, and so it may make more sense to format the time when converting the data object to e.g., JSON.